# Get phone number prefix from Cookies in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, iso, js-cookie

I know that we can get the iso code of a country with this method:

```
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';
const iso = Cookies.get('CK_ISO_CODE');
console.log(iso); // -> 'us'
```

Is there a way to get the phone prefix?

For example, for US it should be +1, for FR +33 and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use this npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/world-countries

First here's an example that works in a snippet. We have to fetch the JSON file, so that eventListener is asynchronous, but if you use the npm package (next example) it won't have to be async.

```js
document.querySelector("#load-prefix").addEventListener("click", async () => {
  const world = await fetch(`https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/world-countries@4.0.0/countries.json`).then(res => res.json())
  const iso = document.querySelector("#iso").value;
  const country = world.find(({cca2}) => cca2.toLowerCase() === iso.toLowerCase());
  const phonePrefixStart = country ? country.idd.root : "unknown";
  const phonePrefixEnd = country ? (country.idd.suffixes.length === 1 ? country.idd.suffixes[0] : "") : "";
  const phonePrefix = phonePrefixStart + phonePrefixEnd;
  document.querySelector("#output").innerText = phonePrefix;
});
```

```html
<input placeholder="iso code" id="iso" />
<button id="load-prefix">Get Phone Prefix</button>
<p id="output"></p>
```

With the npm package, it would look like this. (This example doesn't work because Stack Snippets doesn't include a module bundler)

```js
const world = require('world-countries')
// or
import world from "world-countries";

document.querySelector("#load-prefix").addEventListener("click", () => {
  const iso = document.querySelector("#iso").value;
  const country = world.find(({cca2}) => cca2.toLowerCase() === iso.toLowerCase());
  const phonePrefixStart = country ? country.idd.root : "unknown";
  const phonePrefixEnd = country ? (country.idd.suffixes.length === 1 ? country.idd.suffixes[0] : "") : "";
  const phonePrefix = phonePrefixStart + phonePrefixEnd;
  document.querySelector("#output").innerText = phonePrefix;
});
```

```html
<input placeholder="iso code" id="iso" />
<button id="load-prefix">Get Phone Prefix</button>
<p id="output"></p>
```

So back to your question, it would look something like this:

```js
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';
import world from "world-countries";
const iso = Cookies.get('CK_ISO_CODE');
console.log(iso); // -> 'us'
const country = world.find(({cca2}) => cca2.toLowerCase() === iso.toLowerCase());
const phonePrefixStart = country ? country.idd.root : "unknown";
const phonePrefixEnd = country ? (country.idd.suffixes.length === 1 ? country.idd.suffixes[0] : "") : "";
const phonePrefix = phonePrefixStart + phonePrefixEnd;
console.log(phonePrefix); // -> '+1'
```

Comment: it seems to work somehow but not fully. for example, for all countries that I have tested, it shows only the first digit of the prefix. example: France (fr) has +33 but it only shows +3, Romania (ro) has +40, it shows only +4. Here is the list of all codes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_country_calling_codes

Comment: I would suggest this: `const phonePrefix = country ? country.idd.root + country.idd.suffixes[0] : 'unknown';`

Comment: @JeanPierre Well an array would need to be made in this case, since multiple "suffixes" can exist. Would you rather have an Array of possible codes or just one code? Note that the US has 317 "suffixes"

Comment: yes, in the case of US it would be correct to show only the root as that is the prefix. But in case of Romania, there is no +4, everywhere it is used +40. So I would say that if the array of prefixes contains only one element it should be used, otherwise no.

Comment: Ok I'll add that feature

Comment: @JeanPierre I've updated my answer with that specification